# What does "If a < b < c Then" actually do in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, syntax, operators

Here is some "bad" code:

```
Module test
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("1<2 =   " + cstr((1<2)))
        Console.WriteLine("2<1 =   " + cstr((2<1)))
        Console.WriteLine("1<2<3 = " + cstr((1<2<3)))
        Console.WriteLine("3<2<1 = " + cstr((3<2<1)))
    End Sub
End Module
```

The output from this is:

```
1<2 =   True
2<1 =   False
1<2<3 = True
3<2<1 = True
```

`1<2<3` is True, but not for the right reasons.

`3<2<1` evaluates to True as well. Why?

Can someone explain what's going on here?

I know I should be using `a<b and b<c` but I want to know what happens when you use consecutive operators.  ie, why doesn't the compiler cry!! Is syntax like this used for something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It evaluates it left to right, so `3<2<1` is the same as `(3<2)<1`. Because expression in parentheses is false, the whole thing evaluates to `0<1` which is true.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean me sound pushy. I simply realized that this was the first question you asked yourself and decided to remind you.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, with Option Strict On, the compiler does cry. With Option Strict Off, here's what happens:

- `3 < 2 < 1` is evaluated from left to right, so it's the equivalent to `(3 < 2) < 1`
- `3 < 2` is evaluated to `False` so the compiler evaluates: `False < 1`
- VB converts boolean value `False` to `0`, so that it can be compared with another int value
- `0 < 1` is evaluated to `True`

Comment: If I set the Option Strict to On, and then compare let's say three boolean variable. I think, in that case, compiler will not cry.

Comment: You're right! But comparing boolean values like this makes no sense ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is not specific to any language, but `a<b<c` will always be evaluated as `(a<b) < c`. This holds true for all other operators too. So, `a+b+c` will always be `(a+b) + c`.